# Get ROW number which store Math.min VALUE in CSV file(JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, csv, machine-learning, canvasjs, variable-length

How can I get the row number of the lowest value in csv file `column 4`?

**Notes:**

> Price = Points[4] = column 4 in Csv. file
>  lowestv: find lowest
>   value in Points[4]
>  j = the row number that I want to get
>   (lowestv.length is fault; it's just an example)

After getting the j value, I want to put it into `dataPoints.push({x: new Date(j))` in order to show the date

```
        function getDataPointsFromCSV(csv, int) {
            var dataPoints = csvLines =   [];   
            var j, price;                   
            var lowestv = Infinity;         
            csvLines = csv.split(/[\r?\n|\r|\n]+/);             
            for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
                if (csvLines[i].length > 0) {
                    points = csvLines[i].split(",");
                    price = points[4]                   
                    lowestv = Math.min(price, lowestv)
                    j = lowestv.length
             }          
            for (var i = j; i <= j+10; i++)
                if (csvLines[i].length > 0) {
                    points = csvLines[i].split(",");
                  <!--Another code-->                                   
             }                       
                dataPoints.push({x: new Date(j),y: parseFloat(lowestv)});   
        return dataPoints;
        }
```

Comment: Please click `[<>]` snippet editor to create a [mcve]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59935949/find-math-min-row