# find Math.min row

Tags: javascript, csv, row, min

I have already found the lowest value in a column in a csv file, but I can't find which row store this value. Can someone help me please? Is there anyway I can find the answer by myself though I have googled for many days and websites. Thanks in advance.

```
function getDataPointsFromCSV(csv) {
            var dataPoints = csvLines =   [];   
            var mini, a
            var minIndex = 0
            csvLines = csv.split(/[\r?\n|\r|\n]+/);
            for (var i = 1; i <= csvLines.length; i++)
                if (csvLines[i] > 0) {
                    points = csvLines[i].split(",");
//points instead of csvLines
                    mini = points[4]
                }
            var a = mini                
            for (var i = 1; i <= csvLines.length; i++)
                if (csvLines[i] < mini) {
                    points = csvLines[i].split(",");                    

                    minIndex = i
                    mini = csvLines[i]                                      
// Find lowest value in a column5(=points[4])( but how to find the row that store the lowest value, can someone help me please?)                
                    lowestv = Math.min(price, lowestv)
             }
// example; mini.length          
            for (var i = mini.length; i <= mini.length+10; i++)
                if (csvLines[i].length > 0) {
                    points = csvLines[i].split(",");
                    price = points[4]
            }
                dataPoints.push({x: new Date(),y: parseFloat(minIndex)});   
        return dataPoints;
        }
```

Comment: Is it possible to insert these codes to my program after a little modification?`var col2 = arr.map(function (elem) {
    return elem[1]; //to get all the column 2 values
});

var index = col2.indexOf(Math.max.apply(this, col2));`

Comment: Just for fun: could you add a sample of the CSV (like header + 3 or 4 lines) that you use?

Comment: **date open high low close
31/10/2019 9202.457589 9383.160892 9028.71744 9199.584833
30/10/2019 9422.463325 9426.874217 9085.370357 9205.726559
29/10/2019 9248.440562 9516.181048 9232.648086 9427.687584
28/10/2019 9565.101883 9805.118089 9256.148389 9256.148389
**

Comment: It's more clear.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909191/find-math-min-row-value

Answer (score 0):

I provide a snippet, that uses the sample data in your comment:

```js
const csv = "date,open,high,low,close\n31/10/2019,9202.457589,9383.160892,9028.71744,9199.584833\n30/10/2019,9422.463325,9426.874217,9085.370357,9205.726559\n29/10/2019,9248.440562,9516.181048,9232.648086,9427.687584\n28/10/2019,9565.101883,9805.118089,9256.148389,9256.148389"
const lines = csv.split(/[\r?\n|\r|\n]+/)
const header = lines.shift().split(',') // chop off header, and store it in a variable
const cells = lines.map(e => e.split(',').map(n => !isNaN(n) ? Number(n) : n))

// transpose the array, so it's easier to get min/max
// transposing (rows become columns and columns become rows)
// [[a, b],[c, d]] ==> [[a, c], [b, d]]
const transpose = cells[0].map((e, i) => {
  return cells.map(el => {
    return el[i]
  })
})
const dates = transpose.shift() // chop off dates, and store them in a variable

const rowRange = transpose.map((e, i) => {
  const min = Math.min(...e)
  const max = Math.max(...e)
  return {
    col: i + 1, // +1, because dates are chopped off
    colName: header[i + 1],
    max,
    maxRow: e.indexOf(max) + 1, // +1, because header is chopped off
    maxRowDate: dates[e.indexOf(max)],
    min,
    minRow: e.indexOf(min) + 1, // +1, because header is chopped off
    minRowDate: dates[e.indexOf(min)]
  }
})

console.log("result:", rowRange)
```

I added **min** AND **max** (and a couple of other properties) so you could use it in more cases.

### IMPORTANT NOTE

This solution mutates the array parsed from the CSV.

Answer (score 0):

I would break this into two steps.  First, we parse the CSV to get an array of objects.  Then we iterate over them to find stats like `minVal` and `minRow` (and any others we might want.)  While this is slightly less efficient than doing it in a single pass, it leads to simpler, more maintainable code.

So here we have `csv2arr`, which converts your CSV string into objects that look like this:

```js
{
    date: "31/10/2019",
    open: 9202.457589,
    high: 9383.160892,
    low: 9028.71744,
    close: 9199.584833
}
```

and `stats`, which takes an array of objects like that to find statistics such as `maxVal` and `minRow` for each column.  We could enhance this to find other stats such as `mean` and `median` if desired.  Its output looks like this:

```js
{
    date: { /* ... */ },
    open: { /* ... */ },
    high: { /* ... */ },
    low: { /* ... */ },
    close: {
        minVal: 9199.584833,
        maxVal: 9427.687584,
        minRow: {date: "31/10/2019", open: 9202.457589, high: 9383.160892, low: 9028.71744, close: 9199.584833},
        maxRow: {date: "29/10/2019", open: 9248.440562, high: 9516.181048, low: 9232.648086, close: 9427.687584}
    }
}
```

This is one way to do so:

```js
// Naive, but useful for some data
const csv2arr = (csv) => {
  const [headers, ...rows] = csv .trim () .split ('\n') .map (r => r .split (','))
  return rows .reduce ((a, r) => [
    ... a, 
    Object .assign (... (r .map ((c, i) => ({[headers [i]]: isNaN(c) ? c : Number(c)}))))
  ], [])
}

const stats = (rows) => rows .reduce (
  (stats, row) => Object .assign (
    ... Object .entries (row) .map (([key, val]) => ({[key]: ({
      minVal: key in stats && stats [key] .minVal < val ? stats [key] .minVal : val,
      maxVal: key in stats && stats [key] .maxVal > val ? stats [key] .maxVal : val,
      minRow: key in stats && stats [key] .minRow [key] < val ? stats [key] .minRow : row,
      maxRow: key in stats && stats [key] .maxRow [key] > val ? stats [key] .maxRow : row,
    })}))
  ),
  {}
)

const csv = `
date,open,high,low,close
31/10/2019,9202.457589,9383.160892,9028.71744,9199.584833
30/10/2019,9422.463325,9426.874217,9085.370357,9205.726559
29/10/2019,9248.440562,9516.181048,9232.648086,9427.687584
28/10/2019,9565.101883,9805.118089,9256.148389,9256.148389
`

const rows = csv2arr (csv)
const statistics = stats (rows)

console .log (rows)
console .log (statistics)
```

Note that the min/max values for dates here don't make much sense.  If they were ISO-formatted (e.g. "2019-10-31"), then these values would also get meaningful maximums and minimums.

`csv2arr` is useful for a reasonably wide range of cases.  But don't mistake it for a full CSV parser.  If your data includes cells with commas, for instance, it will fail.  It's also naive about the output.  Essentially, if it looks like a number, it becomes a number, even if other things in the column disagree.  There are other problems, too.  But it's still useful for many comma-delimited formats.

Comment: @Steve: I think that is your decision  to make.  My answer offers two functions.  One converts a CSV string with headers into an array of objects with properties named by those headers.  The other find minimum/maximum values and rows for arrays of such objects.  I haven't looked closely at your code, but I would expect that this combination would be a *replacement* for it, not something it calls.

Comment: I think these functions are not suitable for me because what I want to do is to find `lowestv.length` and put it into loop`for (var i = lowestv.length; i <= lowestv.length+10; i++)` the `var i` start with the row that stored lowest value instead of `var i = 1`

Comment: @Steve: It's quite possible that my functions are no help to you at all.  But they attempt to solve your problem in a general way.  So, for instance, if at the end, you checked `statistics .close .minRow`, you would get a value like:  `{date: "31/10/2019", open: 9202.457589, high: 9383.160892, low: 9028.71744, close: 9199.584833}`.  If that's not the sort of output you want, then this is probably not for you.